# Firestore stops working after clearing site data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, sveltekit

I created a SvelteKit app that uses Firestore as a database. I enabled Firestore persistent storage . Now it works all well, until I clear the site data. Once I clear the site data Firestore just stops working, it's not able to fetch data.

How I can solve this issue? If any user just clears the site data my site won't work again for them  unless they clear the cached data.

After digging around I discovered that the data cached by Firestore still exists in IndexedDB. After deleting the related databases Firestore starts working.